# Why can't I get height of element in backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to reposition an element inside a backbone view after rendering, but can't get the height. I've got a work around with setTimeout, but I'm still very confused and frustrated. Why does height() return `null` only inside the backbone render function??

I've managed to reproduce in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/turpana/3nh9916a/2/

Comment: it takes it a while to "sink in" to the dom. there are some tricks to force a refresh, but if you're doing this a lot (aka in a loop), performance will suffer...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/answers! I think I get it now. Looks like the gist of it is that the element simply isn't in the DOM when I'm trying to access the height.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are inserting the `view.$el` into the DOM after `render` is called as opposed to before. If you specify an `el` when instantiating your view

```
var view = new View( { el : $('.bb-container') } );
```

then `this.$el` in `render` will already be inserted into the DOM and your `height()` will work correctly [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nh9916a/3/):

```
// in backbone view
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html('<p class="hello">hello</p>');
        var heightInline = $('.hello').height();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var heightInTimeout = $('.hello').height();
            $('.heights').append(
                '<p><strong>In backbone view:</strong></p>'
                + '<p>height inline: ' + heightInline + '</p>'
                + '<p>height after 1 ms: ' + heightInTimeout + '</p>'
             );

        }, 1);
        return this;
    }
});
var view = new View( { el : $('.bb-container') } ) 
view.render()
// just jquery
$('.jq-container').html('<p class="hello-again">hello again</p>');
var jqHeightInline = $('.hello-again').height();
$('.heights').append(
    '<p><strong>With just jQuery:</strong></p>'
    + '<p>height: ' + jqHeightInline + '</p>'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `render` like this and you should get a better idea of what's going on:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html('<p class="hello">hello</p>');
    console.log('In render:');
    console.log('There is a .hello:', $('.hello').length !== 0);
    console.log('And it has height:', $('.hello').height());
    console.log('There is a .hello in this.el:', this.$('.hello').length !== 0);
    console.log('And it has height:', this.$('.hello').height());
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('After timeout:');
        console.log('There is a .hello:', $('.hello').length !== 0);
        console.log('And it has height:', $('.hello').height());
        console.log('There is a .hello in this.el:', this.$('.hello').length !== 0);
        console.log('And it has height:', this.$('.hello').height());
    }, 1);
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7c04rma4/

You'll get output in the console like this:

```
In render:
There is a .hello: false
And it has height: null
There is a .hello in this.el: true
And it has height: 0

After timeout:
There is a .hello: true
And it has height: 18
There is a .hello in this.el: true
And it has height: 18
```

You're getting a `null` height because `$('.hello')` is empty. There won't be a `.hello` element in the DOM until *after* your view's `el` has been added to the DOM and that happens *after* `render` returns.

If you switch to `this.$('.hello')`, you'll find the element (since it is inside `this.el` and `this.$` searches inside `this.el`). Of course, you'll get a zero for the height so this isn't terribly useful either. Why is the height zero here? The height is zero because the browser won't know how big that `<p>` is until it has been rendered. Again, this happens *after* `render` returns.

You get useful results inside the `setTimeout` callback because that won't be triggered until after `render` has returned and after everything has been added to the DOM. JavaScript is single threaded so a `setTimeout` callback won't be triggered until the browser gets control again and the browser has cleared its work queue (and that includes the DOM updates and rendering). You'll sometimes see [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) or `setTimeout(..., 0)` calls to take advantage of this.

There are two usual ways out of this dilemma:

1. Use `setTimeout` or `_.defer` trickery to make things happen in the right order. This assumes that the caller will be putting things in the DOM immediately.
2. Add an explicit "you have been rendered and added to the page" callback to your views and make sure that whatever uses your views calls the callback at the appropriate time.